'Attribute Error' when attempting to extract results from a Qiskit experiment
After running the last line of my code which extracts the results of a qiskit entanglement experiment, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'data' 

This code was run with 100% success on 26th August and was set to entangle 32 qubits. On 9th November, the same code was run and terminated with the above error message. The only change on my part was a setting to entangle 64 qubits. If this is not the cause of the error, then something has changed at IBM. What has changed and how do I overcome this problem?
A similar question was asked about a month ago but the response did not make clear how to change the code to resolve this issue. The entirety of my code is listed below. Any suggestions welcome. Thank you in advance.
#Code to entangle a large number of qubits

from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

#Create circuit
n=64
qc = QuantumCircuit(n)

qc.h(0)
for i in range(n-1):
    qc.barrier()
    qc.cx(i,i+1)

qc.measure_all()


#Optimise the problem for execution on quantum hardware
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService #NEED TO RUN THIS EVERY TIME ANY SERVICE IS REQUIRED FROM IBM.

#If you did not previously save your credentials, use the following line instead:
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum", token="<MY_IBM_QUANTUM_TOKEN>") #NEED TO RUN THIS EVERY TIME ANY SERVICE IS REQUIRED FROM IBM.
#service = QiskitRuntimeService()

backend = service.least_busy(simulator=False, operational=True, min_num_qubits=n) #'n' is already set by this point.
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(optimization_level=3, backend=backend)

isa_circuit = pm.run(qc)

#Initialize the Qiskit Runtime Sampler
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import SamplerV2 as Sampler
sampler = Sampler(backend=backend)

#Invoke the Sampler 
job = sampler.run([isa_circuit], shots=10000)
print(f">>> Job ID: {job.job_id()}")
print(f">>> Job Status: {job.status()}")

#Get results 
#job=service.job('<Job ID>') #RUN THIS IF RETRIEVING RESULTS ON A SEPARATE SESSION. 
result = job.result()

#Get results for the first (and only) PUB 
pub_result = result[0]
print(f"Counts for the meas output register: {pub_result.data.meas.get_counts()}")


if you can retrieve your job by specifying its job id, what's type(result[0])?

It is not possible to reproduce the bug, since you instantiate a SamplerV2 with a backend keyword, that doesn't work anymore. It was used with Sampler, which is now deprecated. Can you please check whether your code uses Sampler or SamplerV2? Also, please specify the version of qiskit-ibm-runtime that you're using, along with your qiskit version

I've checked backend parameter for SamplerV2 has been removed in qiskit-ibm-runtime 0.30.0. so it seems OP's using runtime older than that version. When you update qiskit-ibm-runtime to the latest(ver=0.33.2 as of today), just change backend parameter to mode just like sampler = Sampler(mode=backend).

Thanks for you for your answers Tristan and Taketoshi. The code definitely uses SamplerV2, not Sampler. This should be evident from the code itself. As for the version of qiskit-ibm-runtime, there appears no obvious way to check this. Which version is invoked seems to be controlled by IBM, not the user. If this is not true, then how does the user specify which version is called? Thanks again.

Just a quick look at my code again in relation to recent updates announced by IBM, the only item I can see in the list that is remotely relevant is "Upcoming sunset of backend.run" about 2 months before 18/11/2024. As far as I can see my code does not use any "backend.run" services and no other announcements look relevant. It seems therefore that IBM have implemented an update that is unannounced. Any comments welcome.
